# Bring Filter popup to the front, on top of grid

Tags: css, angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm using the AG Grid Community for angular with Material and I'm facing the following issue with the column filter popup panel:
[image]

It's all fine when the filtered rows are more than 4 or 5 rows as the panel shows properly without cutting off. However, when the number of filtered rows gets fewer than 2 or even 3, the panel gets truncated. I have inspected the element and tried to find the selector for it but I can't seem to get the z-index set properly. I'm also hesitant to mess around with the overflow properties as the documentation sort of advises against it. The selectors I've tried to override in my styles.css (global) are `ag-filter` and `ag-menu` as well as `ag-filter-body-wrapper` - all to no avail.

I've read the documentation and there's no configuration for this as well. Is there some sass variable or something that I should be overriding instead?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That behavior it is because the filter is showing within the container. Try setting the css position of the filter to **fixed**. This should allow to the filter to show over the container.

See [this plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/DZE8jdakIGw9YYqd?open=lib%2Fscript.js&preview) for more info

there is a div **outer**, like your table wrapper, and a box aka your filter:

CSS:

```
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
}

#one {
  position: fixed;
  top: 255px;
  left: 10px;
  background: blue;
}

.outer {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: scroll;
  padding-left: 150px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam congue tortor eget pulvinar lobortis.
   
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam congue tortor eget pulvinar lobortis.
    Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nam ac dolor augue.
    
  </p>
  <div class="box" id="one">One</div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the div is showing over the container.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I had to tweak a few things here and there but your general approach of position fixed did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Update 2022: I had the same problem with a newer version of AG Grid, and while trying to solve it I first found this thread. Actually the solution to this problem is described in the AG Grid documentation: You can use popupParent and set it to the body Element as described here:

https://ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/context-menu/#popup-parent

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33466377)